# Issue with deleteAll in cakephp..

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am usign cakephp 2.0. Using the deleteAll function. I am not getting any sort of error by my records are not deleted from DB..

```
public function admin_deleteTutorial($tutorial_id = null){
    if($tutorial_id > 0){
        //          $this->Tutorial->delete($tutorial_id);

        $condition = array('TutorialDiscussion.tutorial_id' => $tutorial_id );
        $this->TutorialDiscussion->deleteAll($condition);

        $this->Session->write('message','Tutorial details deleted successfully.');
        $this->redirect('/admin/tutorials/index/');

    }
}


** Is it required to first find out list of all id's from TutorialDiscussion having tutoril id this $tutorial. or it will delete all itself.** Though records are deleted from TUtorials so I have commented that.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `$cascade` as the second parameter to true. So all related records are also deleted, if `dependent` is also set to true in your model.

[dependent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html)
[cascade](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->TutorialDiscussion->deleteAll($condition,false);
```